# JavaScript with Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 4.1.6 & Ruby 2.1.5

In Javascript I took one Variable x

```
var x= ravi,kant,ashish
```

I want to show output like below

```
["ravi","kant","ashish"]
```

I write this code

```
var x = ravi,kant,ashish

var z = x.map(function(p){ return '"' + p + '"'; }).join(',');
```

If I put `alert(z)`;
the output becomes  `"ravi","kant","ashish"`
and again if I put `alert(z[0])`, it should come `"ravi"` but its coming `"(double quotes)`

Please suggest me how to get the output. I want answer in JS only.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `split()`

```
var str = "How are you doing today Ravi?";
var res = str.split(" "); // ["How", "are", "you", "doing", "today", "Ravi?"]
res[0] // "How"
```

Taking your example

```
var x= "ravi,kant,ashish";
y = x.split(","); // ["ravi","kant","ashish"]
y[0]; // "ravi"
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Hope that helps!

Comment: il explain my quesn in detail below: i have _form.html.haml page in that i written  -@insurance = InsuranceProvider.pluck(:name)        =content_tag :div, class: "insu_information", data:{insurance:@insurance}do                                                               then i want dis value in application.js file for that i written  varx=$('.insu_information').data('insurance'); so if i put alert(x) then value is cming  ravi,kant,ashish  no single quotes neither double quotes nor even bracket is cming  I wana o/p  ["ravi","kant","ashish"] in 1 variable.so that can use this variable onward.

Comment: Thanks..I got The solution..:):)